# Change data to an Array so I can use .toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Building an app displaying data from an api. 
I want to change this data `population: 2324388` returned from api to an Array so I can use .toLocaleString().
I want to display population like this 2,324,388 as currently It is displayed like this 2324388.

Heres my data object:

```
Object
data:
name: "Namibia"
topLevelDomain: [".na"]
alpha2Code: "NA"
alpha3Code: "NAM"
callingCodes: ["264"]
capital: "Windhoek"
altSpellings: (3) ["NA", "Namibië", "Republic of Namibia"]
region: "Africa"
subregion: "Southern Africa"
population: 2324388
latlng: (2) [-22, 17]
demonym: "Namibian"
area: 825615
gini: 63.9
timezones: ["UTC+01:00"]
borders: (4) ["AGO", "BWA", "ZAF", "ZMB"]
nativeName: "Namibia"
numericCode: "516"
currencies: (2) [{…}, {…}]
languages: (2) [{…}, {…}]
translations: {de: "Namibia", es: "Namibia", fr: "Namibie", ja: "ナミビア", it: "Namibia", …}
flag: "https://restcountries.eu/data/nam.svg"
regionalBlocs: [{…}]
cioc: "NAM"
```

Comment: you can simply access it like data.population.toLocaleString() and show it directly

Comment: please share complete data object you are getting

Comment: I've updated to show data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it if `population` is a string or a number:

```
var populationString = (data && data.population && data.population.toLocaleString()) || '';
```

Comment: I tried that and get 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined.

Comment: In that case you are most likely trying to use the population property before it is available. Try this `<span>{info && info.population.toLocaleString()</span>` to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

`.toLocaleString()` is also a method that you can call on `Numbers` 
Here is a link with information regarding `Number.toLocaleString()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

You can create a number from the population data. The format of the api response is unclear, however if it were a JSON Object you could do the following:

```js
let json = { population: 2324388 }
let number = Number(json.population);
console.log(number.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: It is a JSON object. So far i'm displaying it in the DOM like this   `<span>{info.population}</span>` And I display and countries population user clicks on. The population is displayed however not toLocaleString(). So would this work?